# The default mail app in MacOS does not show sender pictures

Tags: macos, email

When *show contact photo* is enabled in the *View* tab, it shows only the sender's name initials instead of photos. Why?

[image: mail view]

Comment: These all seem like bulk messages of some kind. Possibly junk. Are you sure you have images associated with them?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 yeah I checked all emails dating back to 2014 and none of them have a sender's photo

Comment: You need to check whether you've added their photo in Contacts.

Comment: @Tetsujin pretty sure some of them have profile pictures as I can see them in the Gmail app on my iPhone so it should be a bug or settings on Mac that prevent me from seeing the photos

Comment: Not sure what GMail has to do with it. The pictures need to be in Contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Pictures come from your contacts. You need a contact with the email address that sent the email and a contact photo.

Mail will look up the sender's email address in your contacts and show the contact photo if one exists, otherwise it will show one or two letters as seen in your screenshot.

Gmail looks up Google accounts and retrieves contact photos from there. Mail doesn't do this.